# Why is dotnet build not using the specified SDK on global.json?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-cli

I have a global.json with the following contents

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.300"
  }
}
```

This is the output of dotnet --list-sdks

```
2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.105 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

This is the output of donet --list-runtimes

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Yet when I do dotnet build I get the following error

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.
>   Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 2.2.
>   [C:\solutionfolder\projectfolder\Project.csproj]
>   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.
>   Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 2.2.
>   [C:\solutionfolder\projectfolder\Project.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.
>   Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 2.2.
>   [C:\solutionfolder\otherprojectfolder\OtherProject.csproj]
>   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.
>   Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 2.2.
>   [C:\solutionfolder\otherprojectfolder\OtherProject.csproj]
>       0 Warning(s)
>       2 Error(s)

I need help, this is driving me nuts

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution, it seems this Environment System Variable

MSBuildSDKsPath was pointing to the .NET Core 2.1.300 Sdks folder, removing that variable addressed the problem.